# my arch linux laptops unexpectedlu suspend sometime.why?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

my screen goes off unexpectedly even i am watching you tube or i am reading book in my PC.i have to press power button to reactivate.i have installed arch in my laptop.i am experiencing the problem for half a month.
is this due to OS problem or hardware problem?

Comment: Check the power settings and screensaver settings.  It sounds like the keyboard and mouse are idle, so it shuts off the screen even though you're passively looking at something.  There are power settings to turn off the screen after a period of inactivity.  It's also possible there is a screensaver that is blanking the screen.  If the latter, you can disable it while watching.  There are also utilities like `caffeine` you can load that will periodically send an innocuous keystroke so it appears the computer is in use.

Comment: Do you keep cellphones or other magnetic things right next to the laptop?

Comment: no ,i dont keep any thing near my laptop